How to setup a local-only (offline) Wi-Fi AP with Debian/Raspbian?
##Edit##

Error from hostapd: Failed to initialize interface

WiFi adapter: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)

Supported interface modes:
 * IBSS
 * managed
 * AP
 * monitor
 * mesh point
 * P2P-client
 * P2P-GO
 * P2P-device

valid interface combinations:
 * #{ managed } <= 2, #{ AP, mesh point, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 2, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
   total <= 4, #channels <= 1
 * #{ managed } <= 2, #{ P2P-client } <= 2, #{ AP, mesh point, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
   total <= 4, #channels <= 2
 * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ IBSS } <= 1,
   total <= 2, #channels <= 1



##Edit##
I wish to have a standalone app running on a Raspberry Pi (or anything similar with Debian as OS). In addition, I would like to have a web server running on it, displaying app results. On top I would want this to be completely offline.
So in order to achieve this I wish to have the following:

A Debian running machine (possibly a Raspberry Pi), broadcasting Wi-Fi (let's say "My_SSID", with or without WPA key, doesn't matter)
A client with a mobile phone or whatever.
The clients connects to My_SSID, receives an IP address and opens a browser at myapp.local to see the app results.

My problem is that I would like to have a running AP on the Raspberry Pi, and I can't seem to make it work.
I tried using PyAccessPoint but nothing is broadcasting an SSID. So I also tried running an AP using hostapd, but the service would not start (I tried this, but without bridge). I tried a, b and g hardware modes, but still no luck.
I tried all these on my laptop running Debian live, but I don't think this should be a problem.


What errors did hostapd report when it failed to start? 2) What Wi-Fi adapter does your laptop have? (It's probably different from the one your Pi has, so it's not guaranteed that it'll work the same way on both...) 3) Can you run an iw phy on the system and add "Supported interface modes" and "valid interface combinations" to the post?


Thank you for your reply. answers are in the edit ☝.
Do you mean that theoretically the guide on cyberciti would work on a pi? How does one know the appropriate "driver" "channel" and "mode"? :scratching_my_head:
Sorry for being so clueless, I have been daily driving different linux distros for only 15 years or so I am kind of a noob

Do you have the full output from hostapd? Run it with the -d option if needed. If the iw tool works at all with the adapter, then the driver is always nl80211 (unless you have one of those Realtek NICs that still require iwconfig in which case the driver would be wext – this is not actually the hardware driver but one of two Linux APIs by which hostapd talks to the hardware driver).
